# HashMap keeps repeating every previous value SELENIUM, JAVA

Tags: java, selenium, hashmap, csvreader

i have a list of urls and i am opening each line in a browser and then collecting some values into HashMap. When i print the values collected in HashMap, i see that it
repeats every previous value. what am i doing wrong?

here is what the url look like:

---

- https://myurl.com/test1111
- https://myurl.com/test2222
- https://myurl.com/test3333
- https://myurl.com/test4444
- https://myurl.com/test5555

---

and the is what the HashMap print looks like:

---

- test1111 | file available
- test2222 | file available
- test1111 | file available
- test2222 | file available
- test3333 | file not available
- test1111 | file available
- test2222 | file available
- test4444 | file available
- test3333 | file not available
- test1111 | file available
- test2222 | file available
- test4444 | file available
- test5555 | file available
- test3333 | file not available
- test1111 | file available
- test2222 | file available
- test4444 | file available
- test5555 | file available
- test6666 | file available
- test3333 | file not available
- test7777 | file not available

---

here is my entire code:

```
public class Access_file{   
    
    public static void readFile() throws IOException {
        HashMap<String, String> values = new HashMap<String, String>();
        CSVReader reader = null;        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        try  {  
            reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("x_url.csv"), ',');
            String[] nextLine;
            while((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                for(String line : nextLine) {
                    driver.get(line);
                    String[] url_split = line.split("/");
                     String test_url = url_split[4];
                     String availability = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#mySelector']")).getText();
                     values.put(test_url, availability);                     
                 }  
                for(String i : values.keySet()) {
                     System.out.println(i + "|"+ values.get(i));
                 } 
        }                       
    }
        catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you step through this code with a debugger, you'll spot the problem pretty quick.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
for(String i : values.keySet()) {
  System.out.println(i + "|" + values.get(i));
}
```

which seems to be a for statement to do exactly what your output shows: for every element of the var `values`, it is printing a number, a vertical bar, and the value. You do that after every line you read. What did you expect it to do that it's not doing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the `HashMap`: as per `Map`'s contract, it keeps only one copy of each key.

The problem is the point in your program when you print the map: you do it inside the loop that keeps adding new entries to the map. That is why older entries get printed multiple times.

Move the `for` loop outside the `while` loop to fix this problem.

A very useful habit for avoiding such problems in the future is keeping your indentation tidy. This way you would immediately see that your `for` loop is at the wrong level of nesting, which would help you fix the problem, or even avoid introducing it in the first place.